# adding assertion to validate key from structure

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui, assertions

I am using soapUI free version and would like to add two assertions

- First assertion to check keys are always present in response body message
- Validate value is correct for each key -value pair

For example :

```
{
      "data": "",
      "success": ""
      "statuscode": ""
}
```

can anyone point me on how we can acheive this using soapUI free version. Is groovy scripting only way to acheive this ?

Comment: Is that the entire response? or just part of the response?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Script Assertion`](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html) for the request step in the test case to achieve the assertions that you mentioned.

For instance, if you take the example data that you mentioned:

**Script Assertion**:

```
//Below is the key value pair map that you are expecting from response
//So define according to the expaction. Now just showing with example
//values for demonstration
def expectedMap = [data :'', success :'', statuscode :'']

def response = """{
  "data": "",
  "success": ""
  "statuscode": ""
}"""

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
//check if actual response's keys and values are matched with expected map
//Both of your questions are fulfilled by this
assert expectedMap == json, 'Both are not matching'
```

You can quickly try the same online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/5190580250345472)</kbd>

**Output:**
[image]

In case if you want to deal with dynamic response (unlike the above fixed response), then you can use below script instead of the above.

```
def expectedMap = [data :'', success :'', statuscode :'']

assert context.response, 'Response received is either empty or null'

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)

assert expectedMap == json, 'Actual response is not matching with expected data'
```